# How to change of the content root path of Kestrel from command line

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, command-line, kestrel

I am using Visual Studio to build my MVC website, in NET 6.0

When I publish I get an .exe which I can run it loads Kestrel, it outputs

```
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
      Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
      Now listening on: https://localhost:5001
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Production
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: D:\GitHub\myProj\net.myProj.UiTests\bin\Debug\net6.0\uiBinariesForUiTests
```

I open a browser on localhost on port 5001 and all is good - the website works over localhost perfectly

I want to execute this file from within a test directory...

I am using

```
var fileName = outputPath + "\\net5.MyProj.Ui.exe";  
_iisProcess = new Process();
_iisProcess.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
_iisProcess.StartInfo.FileName = fileName;
_iisProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
_iisProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
_iisProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
_iisProcess.Start();
```

The issue this causes is, it changes the content root path from

> D:\GitHub\myProj\net.myProj.UiTests\bin\Debug\net6.0\uiBinariesForUiTests

to

> D:\GitHub\myProj\net.myProj.UiTests\bin\Debug\net6.0

When I execute the .exe, is there a way to explicitly state the content root path?

Comment: i was facing the same issue your question help me understand my problem

Answer (score 1):

Turns out, you need to set the directory

```
_iisProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = outputPath;
```